# Multiple drawing layers in a single opengles 2.0 application

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es-2.0, layer

I am creating an application in opengl es 2.0. I have two drawings in my scene. One is a bar graph and the other is a sphere. My bargraph will be making various transitions like rotations and translations. I want the sphere to control the various transitions of the graph. My main objective is that as my bar graphs performs transitions, my sphere should not.

Can someone assist me as to how do I accomplish this? I guess I create more than one drawing layer? If yes, could you please assist me with the same? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, it is not very clear to me (maybe a mockup image of what are you trying to achieve would help). But speaking in general, there are no drawing layers in OpenGL. You may render two objects with different transformation matrices (=different position and movement) in a single view. In case some clipping is required, one would either use a scissor test, or specify a different viewport for each object (the two approaches give very similar results, the only difference is how the coordinates are calculated).

Answer (score 0):

your request is quite easy and the final result can be achieved using basic OpenGL concepts such as Model Matrix Push/Pop.

You have to perform the following sequence of Matrix Stack Operations.

PUSH MATRIX
PERFORM THE DESIRED TRANSFORMATION (MOVE, ROTATION, SHADERS ETC)
DRAW THE BAR
POP MATRIX

PUSH MATRIX
DRAW THE SPHERE
POP MATRIX

About layers, I don't have enough information about it but it can be achieved for instance by disabling the DEPTH_TEST and respecting the sequence of drawing.

For example

glDisable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
DO THE AFOREMENTIONED DRAWING.

Cheers
Mao